# SqLite header and source version mismatch for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am searching for a way to get rid of the error message

> SqLite header and source version mismatch 2016-04-08 15:09:49
>   fe7d3b75fe1bde41511b323925af8ae1b910bc4d 2015-07-29 20:00:57
>   cf538e2783e468bbc25e7cb2a9ee64d3e0e80b2f

when ,e.g., typing in `sqlite3`. I had to check a python script, using SQLite. I had to overwrite the `libsqlite.so` in my folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` due to a project specific `libsqlite.so-file`.

But older files `libsqlite3.la`, `libsqlite3.so.0` and `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` remained unchanged.
My folder `/usr/local/lib` does not contain any `sqlite` files. I found this hint to change the source_id in the .c- and .h-file:

https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/header-and-source-version-mismatch-bei-sqlite3/2/

I did this for the file `sqlite3.h`, but the file `sqlite3.c` is also missing.

Any other suggestions how I can fix this annoying problem?

**Update:**

After deleting and re-installing `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-dev`, I am receiving the same error message. The delete process also included the deletion of the file `libsqlite3.so`, that was substituted by the use case specific `libsqlite3.so`.

I also deleted the files `libsqlite3.so.0` and `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` in the folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. This leads to the error message:

> sqlite3: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0: cannot open > shared object file: No such file or directory

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the SQLite version that happens to be shipped with your distribution, put all the source files (`sqlite3.h` *and* `sqlite3.c` of the "[amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)") of the desired version into your project, just like any other source file.

Comment: The `sqlite3.c` file is missing.